# Is it possible to add globalize3 to an external ActiveRecord model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1, globalization

I have a project for which I'm using the globalize3 gem to allow for multiple languages. In my own models I just add `'translates field1, field2, etc.'` and the appropriate migrations and it is all working great.

The problems is that I also have some functionality that depends on external gems. For some of those models I would like to add globalize too. I don't have the code for the models to modify directly like I did with the others. Reopening the model doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to add that translates line to models that I don't have direct access to ?

I'm using Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2 in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Could you supply the name of the gem and a model from that gem?

Are the classes namespaced under a module?  If so, you may not be re-opening the classes correctly.  I use the [qwandry](http://rubygems.org/gems/qwandry) gem to examine gems that I've included in my project, so that might be helpful in determining this.  Of course looking at the source on the project's site is also good if it's available.

I assume that what happens when you say it isn't working is that the I18n.locale setting doesn't affect setting/getting the fields, correct?  It would probably complain about there not being a table if it was working but you hadn't yet created the tables.